# ValueError contains new labels when trying to label encode in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I have a dataset which requires label encoding. I am using sklearn's label encoder for the same.

Here is the reproducible code for the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data11 = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction_Type': ['Mortgage', 'Credit reporting', 'Consumer Loan', 'Mortgage'], 
                       'Complaint_reason': ['Incorrect Info', 'False Statement', 'Using a Debit Card', 'Payoff process'],
                       'Company_response': ['Response1', 'Response2', 'Response3', 'Response1'],
                       'Consumer_disputes': ['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'],
                       'Complaint_Status': ['Processing','Closed', 'Awaiting Response', 'Closed']
                       })

le = LabelEncoder()
data11['Transaction_Type'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Transaction_Type'])
data11['Complaint_reason'] = le.transform(data11['Complaint_reason'])
data11['Company_response'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Company_response'])
data11['Consumer_disputes'] = le.transform(data11['Consumer_disputes'])
data11['Complaint_Status'] = le.transform(data11['Complaint_Status'])
```

The desired output should be something like:

```
({'Transaction_Type': ['1', '2', '3', '1'], 
                       'Complaint_reason': ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
                       'Company_response': ['1', '2', '3', '1'],
                       'Consumer_disputes': ['1', '2', '2', '1'],
                       'Complaint_Status': ['1','2', '3', '2']
                       })
```

The problem is when I try to encode the columns:
'Transaction_Type' and 'Company_response' get encoded successfully but the columns 'Complaint_reason', 'Consumer_disputes' and 'Complaint_Status' throw errors.

For 'Complaint_reason':

```
File "C:/Users/Ashu/untitled0.py", line 26, in <module>
    data11['Complaint_reason'] = le.transform(data11['Complaint_reason'])

ValueError: y contains new labels: ['APR or interest rate' 'Account opening, closing, or management'
 'Account terms and changes' ...
 "Was approved for a loan, but didn't receive the money"
 'Written notification about debt' 'Wrong amount charged or received']
```

and similarly for 'Consumer_disputes':

```
  File "<ipython-input-117-9625bd78b740>", line 1, in <module>
    data11['Consumer_disputes'] = le.transform(data11['Consumer_disputes'].astype(str))

ValueError: y contains new labels: ['No' 'Yes']
```

and similarly for 'Complaint_Status':

```
  File "<ipython-input-119-5cd289c72e45>", line 1, in <module>
    data11['Complaint_Status'] = le.transform(data11['Complaint_Status'])

ValueError: y contains new labels: ['Closed' 'Closed with explanation' 'Closed with monetary relief'
 'Closed with non-monetary relief' 'Untimely response']
```

These all are categorical variables with fixed inputs in forms of sentences. Following is the data slice image:

[Categorical Data Label Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EekQU.png)

There are a couple of questions on this on SO but none have been answered successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **fit_transform()** and that's why you are getting error.

**sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder** -> Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1 (from official docs)

Still if you want to encode your classes between 1 and n_classes, you just need to add 1.

```
data11['Transaction_Type'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Transaction_Type'])
data11['Transaction_Type']
```

Output:

```
0    2
1    1
2    0
3    2
Name: Transaction_Type, dtype: int64
```

**Notice** here, LabelEncoder() do encoding in an alphabetical order, it will give a label of 0 to **Consumer Loan** which comes first in alphabetical order. Similarly, it gives a label of 2 to **Mortage** which comes last in order.

Now, you have two ways to encode it, either accept the default output of LabelEncoder like this,

```
data11['Transaction_Type'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Transaction_Type'])
data11['Complaint_reason'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Complaint_reason'])
data11['Company_response'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Company_response'])
data11['Consumer_disputes'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Consumer_disputes'])
data11['Complaint_Status'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Complaint_Status'])
```

Output:

```
        Transaction_Type  Complaint_reason Company_response Consumer_disputes Complaint_Status
0                   2            1              0              1                2
1                   1            0              1              0                1
2                   0            3              2              0                0
3                   2            2              0              1                1
```

OR

```
data11['Transaction_Type'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Transaction_Type'].sort_values()) + 1
data11['Complaint_reason'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Complaint_reason'].sort_values()) + 1
data11['Company_response'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Company_response']) + 1
data11['Consumer_disputes'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Consumer_disputes'].sort_values()) + 1
data11['Complaint_Status'] = le.fit_transform(data11['Complaint_Status'].sort_values()) + 1
```

Output:

```
    Transaction_Type    Complaint_reason    Company_response    Consumer_disputes   Complaint_Status
0   1                      1                  1                      1              1
1   2                      2                  2                      1              2
2   3                      3                  3                      2              2
3   3                      4                  1                      2              3
```

Comment: Yes you are right... silly me.. should have carefully observed the code before posting.. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Since all columns are different, I think you need to initialise `le` for each column:

```
for col in data11.columns:
    le = LabelEncoder()
    data11[col] = le.fit_transform(data11[col])

   Transaction_Type  Complaint_reason  Company_response  Consumer_disputes  \
0                 2                 1                 0                  1   
1                 1                 0                 1                  0   
2                 0                 3                 2                  0   
3                 2                 2                 0                  1   

   Complaint_Status  
0                 2  
1                 1  
2                 0  
3                 1
```

Comment: yes this method would work, but I do not need to initialise le each time, abdur's answer is correct.I missed fit_transform in the one's which were not being converted. But your solution would work too. Thanks :)